# Is "doll" meant to be used only for human like toys? What alternatives for non-human toys are there?

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I want to say something like a teddy bear, but it is not a bear. For example a cat. 
I guess "cat doll" is the literal translation from my language, but sounds wrong to me because I understand doll to be human-like. Am I right? 
Is "cat shaped doll" something a native English speaker child would say?

I want something a child might say, not an adult description like "cat shaped stuffed toy". 
Also, the toy might not be stuffed, eg. It could be made of plastic or wood.

"Cat toy" sounds to me like a toy meant for cats, but perhaps for none-pet animals it works fine? 
eg. Would "monkey toy" describe it, or must I say "monkey shaped toy"?

Comment: As you say, there is a difference between a **cat toy** (a toy for a real cat) and a **toy cat** (a child's toy that looks like a cat). It can get confusing though, because a **toy dog** can mean a very small [breed of dog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_dog).

Comment: 'Something like a teddy bear' is a _soft toy_, but, as Weather Vane says the general term is _toy [animal]_

Comment: I had a toy dog when I was very small. I loved him, and saw nothing odd about his wheels, or the handle that I used to push him along.

Comment: Thank you! "toy [animal]" is the expression I was looking for!  If any of you want to answer with this solution, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2):

The expression I was looking for is "toy animal"

Thanks